# Last date/time the user logged in

Tags: login

I think someone is trying to use my notebook without my permission.
I was thinking about an option like last logged date/time to check...
Is there something like that in ubuntu?
How can I enable it?

Comment: Cant't find it at the moment but there IS a topic on AU that has a list of all these kind of commands.

Comment: here is one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45711/need-software-to-track-login-and-logoff-timings (not entirely a dupe though)

Comment: cf. http://askubuntu.com/questions/390201/how-to-see-login-history : use `last` or look at `/var/log/auth.log`, `lastlog` doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the command `last`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and just run:

```
last
```

Comment: There are so many commands to learn, this one is brilliant, thank you

Comment: if you want to filter the users just type in `last username`

Comment: @MrSeed `last $USER` for the current user :) `last tty7` works too: it will show things related to the desktop.