# How to see Login history?

Tags: login, log

Is it possible to see the login history, i mean to see if someone has used the computer in my absence and when he used it .
if it is possible, where can i get the log ?
if not, is there a program that logs all the logins and their time ?

Comment: try `last`  in terminal

Comment: or if you want to save it in a file (say userlogin.log) use `last > userlogin.log`

Comment: Following @suhailvs advice, you can add `last | less` if it's too much information. You can use same `vim` commands to search for something.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

That contains a lot more than just plain logins (sudo calls, etc) but logins are in there too. It's protected so you'll need to be root to read it:

```
sudo less /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: Exact command to print failed login history: `sudo grep 'authentication failure' /var/log/auth.log | grep -v "sudo"`. Example output line: `Feb 19 14:35:02 comp-name-1 compiz: pam_unix(unity:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1001 euid=1001 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=ld`. Command to print successful login history: `sudo grep 'login keyring' /var/log/auth.log | grep -v "sudo"`. Example output line: `Feb 18 07:17:58 comp-name-1 compiz: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring`. Probably it shows only logins after last reboot. Sudo is excluded because otherwise our own command would be also listed.

Comment: `sudo grep login.*session.*opened.*USERNAME /var/log/auth.log | grep -v sudo | less -N`

Comment: Even when it works, it does not report the year, only appears the user, day and time among other things

Answer (score 76):

As Suhail mentioned in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390201/how-to-see-login-history#comment499199_390201), the [`last`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/last.1.html) command will show a listing of last logged in users.

Answer (score 34):

To view the most recent login for all accounts on the system, try `lastlog`. There's a few useful options, such as viewing only a specific user.

Comment: This tells me that no one has ever logged in (which is clearly false as I am logged in to run it)

Comment: My lastlog output is wrong too - two of my users have entries (both wrong) and one has "never logged in".

Comment: FYI: Looks ok on Ubuntu18

Answer (score 8):

Well appending your question and oli's answer if you are on **laptop** then you can also check it through grepping the exact content like

```
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "Lid opened"
```

or

```
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "Lid closed"
```

and whether he/she perform any kind of activity through sudo permission by

```
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "session opened for user root"
```

or

```
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "session closed for user root"
```

It will give you extra information what you want to know about user's logged in your system without your permission :):)

Comment: I also use `sudo grep 'login keyring' /var/log/auth.org` to check the login history.

Comment: Caution about "Lid closed" : This only works if the user closed the lid to suspend the laptop. If the user used the suspend-button, it obviously wouldn't log anything. Note as well that if the user suspends the computer first, and then closes the lid, then upon reopening the lid lateron, both events (lid closed + lid opened) will be logged with the same timestamp.

Comment: @TaoWang : perfection :)

Answer (score 0):

To see the last boot or login of your system and users, you can use the command `who` with plenty of options.

```
who -a
```