# time of all guest session login in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login, time, session

It seems that someone has been using my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 through the guest session login. I will disable but I would like to know if is it there any possibility to check the date and time of all guest session logins. Is it possible to verify that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/390201/how-to-see-login-history

Answer (score 2):

Use the `last` command:

```
$ last | grep guest
guest-3j tty8         :1               Thu Jan 26 16:07 - 16:07  (00:00)
guest-i1 tty8         :1               Thu Jan 26 16:07 - 16:07  (00:00)
```