# What domain users have or have not logged into my Ubuntu VM?

Tags: 16.04, login, google

I have a VM with Ubuntu 16.04.1 on it dedicated to be a 2 factor authentication server for Horizon View. It is attached to my windows domain, and users login via SSH to activate their 2 FA. I would love to know how many of my users have done so as 2 FA is not yet required to login, but will be soon. I'd like to find out either by checking if they've logged in before to Ubuntu, or if there's a list from Google Authenticator I could pull.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see Login history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390201/how-to-see-login-history)

Comment: I checked out that post. I only got about 2-3 days worth of logs. Maybe 6-7 user names i saw skimming thru hundreds of lines of logs. :( BUT, the last or last log might be useful. Can this be exported to a file?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do lastlog > log.txt to export the log to a text file.

Then I used FTP to put it on a windows server I had for other purposes, to get the file off.